# xCode can't Control-drag into .m file

Tags: xcode

I'm trying to change the results field in the sample app `SimpleURLConnections` in the AppleDeveloper Library from an Image View Object in the `GetController.m` to a Text View so that it will display responses that aren't images.  (I know some code that checks the response type also needs to change.)

When I drag a Text View object (or ANY object) from the Utilities pane to the `MainWindow.xib` in the editor pane, it appears to be created ok but when I try to Control drag from the Text View into the `@property` area of `GetController.m`, I don't get any "Insert Outlet.." popup or new entry in the `GetController.m` file? (By experimentation, I can get it to populate an `IBOutlet` in the `AppDelegate.m` file.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks,

Rick

Comment: Is the `ViewController` that contains your Text View assigned to `GetController`? (Identity Inspector > Custom Class > Class)

Answer (score 0):

It may be because you are doing it wrong.You added the textview to mainWindow and `Getcontroller` is a controller entity[its a view controller i think.] .An xib will be connected to the outlet if and only if it has the custom class  correctly set to that class.

Add a view controller with custom class in attribute inspector set to that `Getcontroller` and then you can connect the outlet

Answer (score -1):

When u drag the control to the **.m , u should press the key "control",